# Django Rest Framework serializer for an M2M relationship with an in-between joining table

Tags: django-rest-framework, many-to-many, django-serializer

I have 2 models(Programme & Course) with a many-to-many relationship modelled using a joining table(ProgrammeCourse) in-between. How can I write a rest_framework serializer such that for each programme, I should also have course objects nested under it? Here's the sample code for reference:

Models

```py
class Programme(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(choices=PROGRAMME_TITLES, max_length=10)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    faculty = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)

class Course(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    credits = models.IntegerField()
    semester = models.IntegerField(
        choices=((1, 'A'), (2, 'B')), blank=True, default=None)

class ProgrammeCourse(models.Model):
    progID = models.ForeignKey(
        Programme, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="courses")
    courseID = models.ForeignKey(
        Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="programmes")
    isElective = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

For an instance of a Programme, I need an output like this:

```
{title: 'BSc',
name: 'programmeName',
faculty: 'facName',
 courses: [
     {code: 'courseCode1',
      name: 'courseName1'
     },
     {code: 'courseCode2',
      name: 'courseName2'
     },
 ]
}
```

I've tried following the docs, adding the ManyToManyField() under Course, however, I thought this approach *violated the idea of **normalized tables***, hence the use of a joining table in-between. I also read up on the [ManyToManyField with a Through model](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/?fbclid=IwAR3nTizS0TCb14NBnDOCJnWy2zYb6AtI91su7xn2oYa6otf5BRECxdGrK64#manytomanyfields-with-a-through-model) which also seemed to raise the same problem. Is there a way I can use an in-between joining table to achieve the above output?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `ManyToManyField`, you can try using sth like:

```py
class CourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = ('code', 'name')


class ProgrammeCourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    courseID = CourseSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = ProgrammeCourse
        fields = ('courseID',)


class ProgrammeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    courses = ProgrammeCourseSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Programme
        fields = ('title', 'name', 'faculty', 'courses')
```

Hope it works

Comment: You're a genius! It worked like a charm! Thank you very much!